# H3 api call edgeLength always throws exception

Tags: java, h3

I'm tasked migrating a java application using H3 api version 3.6.0 to 4.1.1, and I've been dropped into this application and don't know how the api works.  There is a call to the method edgeLength that worked in version 3, but I cannot get any parameters to work with it.

```
h3.edgeLength(9, LengthUnit.km)
```

The error thrown is

```
Directed edge argument was not valid
com.uber.h3core.exceptions.H3Exception: Directed edge argument was not valid
    at com.uber.h3core.NativeMethods.edgeLengthKm(Native Method)
    at com.uber.h3core.H3Core.edgeLength(H3Core.java:889)
    ...
```

I paused at the point of invocation and tried numbers from 0 to 15, then up to 100, tried using the version that takes a hex address, things like that, but always the same exception.

This call worked when the api version was 3.6.0, but not at 4.1.1.  I can't step into the api in the debugger because the implementation is native, so I'm at a loss.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I just changed the call to be getHexagonEdgeLengthAvg and the test case that failed previously now passes.  Not sure if this change is right or not.

Comment: That change is correct - many of the function names changes between H3v3 and H3v4